# SAS removing " from text

Tags: text, replace, sas

When I tried to remove `"` from a text I mentioned, that `translate` and `tranwrd` creating a blank instead. Only `compress` delivers the wanted result. Why the two others replace `"` with blank?

```
data test;
  a = 'this is my:"funny text"';
  b = translate(a,"",'"');
  c = tranwrd(a,'"',"");
  d = compress(a,'"');
run;
```

The results (d is the wanted one):

- b: this is my: funny text
- c: this is my: funny text
- d: this is my:funny text

Please consider the blank between `: f`for b and c.

Comment: Best to read the documentation on these functions, it is explained well there that TRANSLATE and TRANWRD will not replace a value with a null.  The docs also explain how TRANSTRN may be used to do so, by specifying the third argument as TRIMN("").

Comment: @Quentin, surely that should be the answer?

Comment: @AllanBowe well, it started as just a "RTFM" comment.  Then I went a bit further than I intended, but didn't feel like putting in the effort to make it a complete answer with an example etc.